# parse element from Select List to $_POST to write to database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently making a registration form and pasting all elements via $_POST
Like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your username" name="username" value="<?php echo @$username; ?>">
```

My problem is I want to make a Select list

```
<select name="Icecream Flavours">
    <option value="double chocolate">Double Chocolate</option>  
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>    
    <option value="strawberry" selected>Strawberry</option> 
    <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
</select>
```

and paste the selected argument as I would paste the input text from the input field above.

I managed to do it via list, but it looks messy and sometimes does not work with all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoor first line of code should be:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your username" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:null; ?>">
```

Using the surpressor operator `@` is an overkill and slows down your script for no reason.

For your select field I would store the values in an array and then loop over it and compare the `$_POST` value against each array entry, if `true` add `selected` to the option output.

So your code becomes somewaht like that

```
<?php

$myOptions = array(
    'double' => 'Double chocolate', 
    'vanilla' => 'Vanilla', 
    'strawberry' => 'Strawberry'
    /* and so on */
);

?>

<select name="Icecream_Flavours">

<?php

foreach($myOptions as $key => $opt) {
   $selected = (!isset($_POST['Icecream_Flavours']) || $key != $_POST['Icecream_Flavours'])?null:' selected';

   echo '<option value="' . $key . '"' . $selected. '>' . $opt . '</option>';
}

?>

</select>
```

Comment: I kinda knew about that, but did not find the alternative, thanks for the answer. However, I get this error:    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\spr\register.php on line 147

Comment: @Cataneo it's `isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';`

Comment: Forgot the closing bracket of `isset()`function. Edited it in my answer.

Comment: missing -> ) -----> isset($_POST['username'])

Comment: TiMESPLiNTER, works as a charm ! Thank you ! I Appreciate it :)